Nextjs and Kinde auth issue
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from "next/image";
import { RegisterLink, LoginLink } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/components";

const NavBar: React.FC = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [categoriesOpen, setCategoriesOpen] = useState(false);
  const [mobileCategoriesOpen, setMobileCategoriesOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const toggleCategories = () => {
    setCategoriesOpen(!categoriesOpen);
  };

  const toggleMobileCategories = () => {
    setMobileCategoriesOpen(!mobileCategoriesOpen);
  };

  return (
    <nav className="bg-white shadow-lg font-semibold relative z-50">
      <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4">
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          <div className="flex space-x-4">
            <div>
              <Link href="/" className="flex items-center py-5 px-2 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900" passHref>
                <Image src="/mainimages/logo.png" alt="Brand Logo" width="100" height="100" className="mr-1" />
              </Link>
            </div>

            {/* Primary Navbar items */}
            <div className="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-1 relative">
              <div>
                <button onClick={toggleCategories} className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 flex items-center relative z-50">
                  Categories
                  <svg className="h-5 w-5 ml-1 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z" clipRule="evenodd" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
                {categoriesOpen && (
                  <div className="absolute left-0 top-full z-50 mt-2 w-56 bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg">
                    <div className="p-4">
                      <div className="group relative flex flex-col gap-y-4">
                        <div className="group relative flex items-start gap-x-2 rounded-lg p-2 text-sm leading-6 hover:bg-gray-50">
                          <div className="flex-auto">
                            <span className="block font-semibold text-gray-900">Creative & Visual Media</span>
                            <div className="pl-4 mt-2 space-y-2 font-normal">
                              
                              <Link href="#" className="block text-gray-600 hover:text-yellow-600">Graphic Design</Link>
                              <Link href="#" className="block text-gray-600 hover:text-yellow-600">Video Production</Link>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="group relative flex items-start gap-x-2 rounded-lg p-2 text-sm leading-6 hover:bg-gray-50">
                          <div className="flex-auto">
                            <span className="block font-semibold text-gray-900">Content Creation</span>
                            <div className="pl-4 mt-2 space-y-2 font-normal">

                              <Link href="#" className="block text-gray-600 hover:text-yellow-600">Writing</Link>
                              <Link href="#" className="block text-gray-600 hover:text-yellow-600">Translate</Link>
                              
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
              <Link href="/projects" className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">
                Projects
              </Link>
              <Link href="/blog" className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">
                Blogs
              </Link>
              <Link href="/aboutus" className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">
                About Us
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* Secondary Navbar items */}
          <div className="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-1">
            <div className="text-black hover:text-gray-600 mx-5">
              <LoginLink>Login</LoginLink>
            </div>
            <div className="px-4 py-2 rounded-full bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-600 text-black font-semibold">
              <RegisterLink>Sign Up</RegisterLink>
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* Mobile button goes here */}
          <div className="md:hidden flex items-center">
            <button className="mobile-menu-button" onClick={toggleMenu}>
              <svg
                className="w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-600"
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Mobile menu */}
      <div className={`mobile-menu ${isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'} md:hidden`}>
        <Link href="/projects" className="block py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200 text-black">
          Projects
        </Link>
        <Link href="/blog" className="block py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200 text-black">
          Blogs
        </Link>
        <Link href="/aboutus" className="block py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200 text-black">
          About Us
        </Link>
        <div className="relative">
          <button onClick={toggleMobileCategories} className="block w-full text-left py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200 text-black">
            Categories
            <svg className="inline-block w-4 h-4 ml-2 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z" clipRule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
          </button>
          {mobileCategoriesOpen && (
            <div className="pl-4">
              <div className="py-2">
                <span className="block font-semibold text-gray-900">Creative & Visual Media</span>
                <div className="pl-4 mt-2 space-y-2 font-normal">
                  
                  <Link href="#" className="block text-gray-600 hover:text-yellow-600">Graphic Design</Link>
                  <Link href="#" className="block text-gray-600 hover:text-yellow-600">Video Production</Link>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="py-2">
                <span className="block font-semibold text-gray-900">Content Creation</span>
                <div className="pl-4 mt-2 space-y-2 font-normal">

                  <Link href="#" className="block text-gray-600 hover:text-yellow-600">Writing</Link>
                  <Link href="#" className="block text-gray-600 hover:text-yellow-600">Translate</Link>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <Link href="/login" className="block py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200 text-black">
          <LoginLink>Login</LoginLink>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/RegEntPage" className="block py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200 text-black">
          <RegisterLink>Sign Up</RegisterLink>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;


import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import LogoutLink from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/components";

export async function UserNav() {
  const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
  const user = await getUser();

  return (
    // other things..
    user ? (
      <>
        <div className="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-1">
          <div className="text-black hover:text-gray-600 mx-5">
            <LogoutLink>Login</LogoutLink>
          </div>
          <div className="px-4 py-2 rounded-full bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-600 text-black font-semibold">
            <Link href="/pages/dashbord">Dashboard</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    ) : (
      <>
        <div className="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-1">
          <div className="text-black hover:text-gray-600 mx-5">
            <LoginLink>Login</LoginLink>
          </div>
          <div className="px-4 py-2 rounded-full bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-600 text-black font-semibold">
            <RegisterLink>Sign Up</RegisterLink>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  );
}


I need to merge these two codes. can anyone help me to make this? when i try to do it it says there is a server-side function and it cannot be used on the browser side.
I tried to merge these codes together and got an error like there is a server-side function and cannot use on the browser side
I also tried to merge these codes together and got an error message like there is a server-side function and cannot use on the browser side.
please help me to make this

I think you might want to use useKindeBrowserClient hook as the first code you provided runs in the client side. Something like:
const { user } = useKindeBrowserClient();

instead of:
const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
const user = await getUser();

